# How to set x-priority header = null while using plugin WP e-commerce?

Tags: headers, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am looking for the files which are responsible for sending the email in WP e-commmerce, because i need to set the x-priority header = null

I already tried a general function in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('phpmailer_init','update_priority_mailer');
function update_priority_mailer($mailer){
    $mailer->Priority = '';
    return $mailer;
}
```

but that didn't work

#### EDIT

I see line 911

```
$result .= $this->HeaderLine('X-Priority', $this->Priority); in wp-includes\class-phpmailer.php
```

might be the one that i need to alter.
But as i don't want to edit WP source files how can i filter this??

#### EDIT2

Above function did filter the X-Priority but mail-tester still gives the warning

> 1.6 XPRIO Has X-Priority  header *

Searching where this X-Priority comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you are trying to set a header propery which already been used to create header.

So what I would suggest is set the property and then call the `createHeader()` function so now again when building header your changed property should work.

You don't have to use `filter` you can use the `action` hook itself as the action is `refernce` to the gobal `phpmailer`

Example

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'update_priority_mailer' );
function update_priority_mailer( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Priority = 5; //can be 1, 3, 5
    //now again construct the header so the change property will be used
    $phpmailer->createHeader();   
    // since $phpmailer is an reference variable everything will be updated   

}
```

You can also check other methods `addCustomHeader()`

Comment: hmm, i see X-Priority being set
`X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.4`
 but with mail-tester.com i still get the warning 
`*  1.6 XPRIO Has X-Priority
 header`

Comment: can you try the same with your own gmail too. From your inbox just check for view message details, where you can see more headers details too

Comment: sent a mail to my gmail account and look into the message details, but here i can't see anything strange. X-Priority is set to 5 as i tested